# No logro como crear una solución a que agregue la propiedad y que sea null

Tags: javascript

Cordial  saludo e intentado por muchos medios, al menos con una guía sería suficiente.

Porque no logro sintonizar la llamada propiedad con el tema de `null`, si alguien me puede decir un tutorial donde veo como hacerlo o darle la solución para entender la lógica, muchas gracias.

```
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
  // La funcion llamada 'agregaPropiedad' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene
  // en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que puede tener como propiedades 'nombre' o 'edad'. También
  // recibe un string llamado 'propiedad'.
  // Esta funcion debe agregar la propiedad 'propiedad' y setearla en null a aquellos objetos dentro de 'amigos' que no tengan esa propiedad
  // Debe devolver el array 'amigos' modificado.
  // Nota: Si el objeto dentro de 'amigos' tiene esa 'propiedad' no modificarla.
  // Ej:
  // var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
  // agregaPropiedad(amigos, 'edad') debe devolver [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: null } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }]

  amigos.forEach(function (amigos) {
    if (!amigos.hasOwnProperty(propiedad)) {
      amigos[propiedad] = null;
    }
  });
}

let amigos = [
  {
    name: "Toni",
  },
  {
    name: "Emi",
    edad: 25,
  },
];
let amigosModificado = agregaPropiedad(amigos, "edad");
```

Comment: Me parece que el enunciado es claro. ¿Qué has investigado/intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? El objetivo del sitio no es ofrecer tutoriales, sino resolver problemas concretos. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Se trata de recorrer el array y, para cada elemento comprobar si existe la propiedad con el nombre dado. Si no es así, la añades con valor null: `amigo[propiedad]=null`, por ejemplo

Comment: a osea que si la propiedad no tiene ningún valor, le debo agregar null o este viene por defecto?

Comment: Lee el enunciado, está claramente explicado lo que tienes que hacer. Inténtalo y si tienes algún problema te ayudaremos a resolverlo.

Comment: amigos.forEach(function (amigos) {
    if (!amigos.hasOwnProperty(propiedad)) {
        amigos[propiedad] = null; 
    }
  })
  
  return array;


let amigos = [
    {
    name: 'Toni'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Emi',
    edad: 25
  }
];

let amigosModificado = addProperty(amigos, 'edad');
}

Comment: es lo que llevo de codigo pero no me sirve.

Comment: Compañeros, he añadido el código que se ha publicado en comentarios. Xonmek para la próxima añade el código completo o una parte para que nosotros podamos reproducir el problema más fácil y poder darte una solución.

Answer (score 2):

La solución que se me ocurre y la que yo haría, es la siguiente

```js
/**
 * Añade una propiedad dinamicamente a un objeto(si no existe) 
 * dentro de un array y devuelve un NUEVO ARRAY
 */
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {

  if(propiedad) {
    //La propiedad esta definida, añadimos dinámicamente dicha pripiedad 
    //al objeto QUE NO LO TENGA con el valor por defecto(null)
    
    //Usando el operador ternario, podemos saber si la propiedad existe o no.
    //En caso que no existe se usa Object.assign para modificar el objeto
    return amigos.map(amigo => propiedad in amigo ? amigo: Object.assign(
       amigo, {[propiedad]: null})
      );
  };
  
  //Si no hay propiedad, simplemente se devuelve el array de amigos
  return amigos;
                 
}

let amigos = [
  {
    name: "Toni",
  },
  {
    name: "Emi",
    edad: 25,
  },
];

//Si quieres mantener el array por defecto(amigos), simplemente le asignas el valor 
//del return a otra variable y si no se lo asignas a la variable "amigos"
let amigosModificado = agregaPropiedad(amigos, "edad");
console.log(amigosModificado)
```

> Hay una serie de validaciones que yo personalmente haría, pero tu puedes adaptar el código a tus necesidades.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```
    function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {    
    amigos.forEach(function (amigos) {
        if (propiedad === undefined) {
            propiedad = "edad";
            amigos[propiedad] = null;
        };
    });
    return console.log(amigos);
}

let amigos = [
    {
        name: "Toni",
    },
    {
        name: "Emi",
        edad: 25,
    },
];

agregaPropiedad(amigos)
```

Comment: Es una solución rápida, pero efectiva, en realidad te estoy dando un ejemplo de como debería ser según mi opinión, cuando hacemos una función y hay parámetros indefinidos podemos comprobar si estos son "undefined" y establecerles una condición para cuando esto suceda, en mi caso lo hice con un retorno en consola para comprobarlo,

Comment: La explicación va en la respuesta amig@ y no en la zona de comentarios, por favor edita y agrega la ahí

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes intentar este codigo. Solo he cambiado una linea a tu código actual en la forma de comparar la propiedad. !(propiedad in amigo)
Por otro lado la funcion no devuelve el array ya que la estas llamando en el mismo ambito.

```
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
        // La funcion llamada 'agregaPropiedad' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene
        // en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que puede tener como propiedades 'nombre' o 'edad'. También
        // recibe un string llamado 'propiedad'.
        // Esta funcion debe agregar la propiedad 'propiedad' y setearla en null a aquellos objetos dentro de 'amigos' que no tengan esa propiedad
        // Debe devolver el array 'amigos' modificado.
        // Nota: Si el objeto dentro de 'amigos' tiene esa 'propiedad' no modificarla.
        // Ej:
        // var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
        // agregaPropiedad(amigos, 'edad') debe devolver [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: null } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }]

        amigos.forEach(function (amigo) {
            if (!(propiedad in amigo)) {
                amigo[propiedad] = null;
            }
        });


    }

    var amigos = [
        {
            name: "Toni",
        },
        {
            name: "Emi",
            edad: 25,
        },
    ];
    agregaPropiedad(amigos, "edad");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(amigos));
    //[{"name":"Toni","edad":null},{"name":"Emi","edad":25}]
```

Comment: Por favor añade la explicación de tu código. Saludos.